# How to find post URL in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url

I'm trying to display the URL in rails but it returns an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `url' for #<Post:0x000000058ea918>
```

What method can I use?

Answer (score 1):

Type `rake routes` in the Rails Console, to see the list of routes in your working application. And, don't forget to put the `_path`in the end eg: `posts_path`.

Answer (score -1):

Found it: `url_for(@post)`, this will display (in my case) 'posts/ID' if you want the full URL you can add it manually before it.